# Python Bs4 cannot have the plain text inside a double span <span class="something"><span class="else"> damn text </span></span>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey guys so I'm trying to scrape the Indeed website and so far everything has been working well except for the salary (lol of course).

So I am far from an expert in requests, requests_html, and bs4
and so after a good hour of looking everywhere, I cannot find an answer to my particular problem so here I am ...

I have shortened the code to make things easier (I  will scrape more whatevs)
yet I have let as example a span with .text which works fine but only one span is there, not a span in a span like in the salary:

```html
<div class="salarySnippet salarySnippetDemphasizeholisticSalary">
<span class="salary no-wrap">
<span class="salaryText">
1 900 € - 2 100 € par mois</span>
</span>
</div>
```

I'm French so Indeed is in French version if you wanna try yourself go for Paris or else in the input:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req

print("_____Indeed Job Scaper_____")
city = str(input("Enter your city name here: "))

url = ("https://www.indeed.fr/emplois?l=" + city)
u_req = req.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(u_req.content, 'html.parser')
job_elems = soup.find_all('div' , class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard') 

for job_elem in job_elems:
    compagny_name = job_elem.find('span' , class_="company")
    salary = job_elem.find("span", {"class": "salaryText"})

    print(compagny_name.text)
    print(salary.text)
```

If I do not ask print .text on salary I will get:

```html
<span class="salaryText">
1 800 € - 4 000 € par mois</span>
```

Comment: And what's the result of your code sample? Does it return the expected value?

Comment: ow ya sorry no  if i do print(salary.text) python will return ```print(salary.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ```

Comment: And if you print `salary` ?

Comment: Looks like there are missing pieces in your example.    
Where do the `class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard` and `class_="company"` come from?

Comment: mate they come from the url

Comment: mate they come from the url

Comment: Which URL? Classes are not part of an URL.

I would expect to see an HTML sample containing at least the objects you're trying to query, to be able to help.

Comment: the hmtl code is horribly long you better use my code to see for yourself or got to the url and do a Ctrl + u

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this `salaryText` span does not exist for every card. So, In your loop, you'll need to check if the span exists before accessing it's inner text.

Here is an updated version of your code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req

print("_____Indeed Job Scaper_____")
city = str(input("Enter your city name here: "))

url = ("https://www.indeed.fr/emplois?l=" + city)
u_req = req.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(u_req.content, 'html.parser')
job_elems = soup.find_all('div' , class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard') 

for job_elem in job_elems:
    compagny_name = job_elem.find('span' , class_="company")
    salary = job_elem.find("span", {"class": "salaryText"})

    print(compagny_name.text)

    # check if salary is not none, before accessing it's text property. 
    if salary: 
        print(salary.text)
```

Could you let me know if it works?

Comment: thx mate i didn't properly did the recon job checking if all annouces had the elements i wanted i added a ```else: print("No salary") ``` work perfectly now